# A simple question regarding the derivation of the Black-Scholes formula

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, finance, stochastic-pde

i am taking a derivatives class, and what is of course obligatory is to derive the Black Scholes formula. I am simply stuck or puzzled by one simple thing in the derivation:

How do they get from 
$$exp(y-\frac{(y-logS_0 - (r - 1/2 \sigma^2)T)^2}{2\sigma^2 T})$$

to

$$S_0e^{rT} exp(-\frac{(y-logS_0 - (r + 1/2 \sigma^2)T)^2}{2\sigma^2 T})$$

Comment: Those expressions are not equal.  Take $S_0=T=1$, $\sigma^2=\frac 12$ and $r=0$ to see that the top is $\exp\left(y-(y+1)^2\right)$ and the bottom is $\exp\left((y+1)^2\right)$.

Comment: Sorry I missed a minus sign. What do you think of this now. These are my proffesors slides so could be wrong. $$S_0e^{rT} exp(-\frac{(y-logS_0 - (r + 1/2 \sigma^2)T)^2}{2\sigma^2 T})$$ I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the equation to be true, using the property that $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$,

it is true if

$$\exp(y)=S_o\exp(rT)$$

That is if $y$ is defined to be the logarithm of the value after time $T$ with interest rate $r$.

That is there must be a relationship between $y$ and $S, r,T$.